# test file to library file, array not being read in properly issue in c

Tags: c

So my c code is not properly reading in the array being passed in to the library function I created. It for some reason is outputting size 4, when it is size 10, etc. Please help me make this work. The library is included in the file header.

```
int main()
{
// data of array
double input[] = {30.0, 90.0, 100.0, 84.0, 72.0, 40.0, 34.0, 91.0, 80.0, 62.0};
// size of array
int size = sizeof(input)/sizeof(double);

// getting information from library based on data of array
printf("The mean is: %.2f", calculateMean(size, input));
}
```

// This is the library 
   //returns the mean of data

```
double calculateMean(int totnum, double data[])
{

double total = 0;
int size = sizeof(data)/sizeof(double);


for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    total += data[i];

}
return (double)total/size;
}
```

Comment: Remember that arrays are passed to functions as pointers.

Comment: how would I do so. please clarify.

Comment: `return (double)total/size;` -- The cast is unneccessary.

Answer (score 1):

In `calculateMean` you use

```
int size = sizeof(data)/sizeof(double);
```

to get the size of `data`. But the array is passed to function as a pointer.
So your `size` may be initialize to `0` (As in most platforms `sizeof(double) > sizeof(double*)`)

You pass `totnum` to the function but don't use it. Using it you can solve the problem

```
double calculateMean(int totnum, double data[])
{

    double total = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<totnum; i++)
    {
        total += data[i];

    }
    return (double)total/totnum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your functin  `double calculateMean(int totnum, double data[])` you dont need to calculate `size` again as you pass `totnum` use it instead of `size` -

```
int size = sizeof(data)/sizeof(double);   // useless in function.
```

This should not be done in any function when passing array as it is computed as -

```
sizeof(double *)/sizeof(double)  // computing size uncorrect.
```